# stop django from logging out after source changes

Tags: django, session

I'm working on a django project and since a few days django keeps logging me of after I change a source file.

The expire date in the cookies and in the database show that theres still 1 month left.

Even after making the change the session cookie is the same as in the database but I have to login again. and after logging in both sessionids (database and browser) change.

I'm using django 1.8.5

edit:
some session related settings:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE        False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY                True
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN                  None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST             False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE                  False
```

edit2:

Just to be a bit more clear: After changing some source file (python files, templates work just fine) the server will reload (if I use --noreload, I have to do it manually to get the changes), after that everyone is logged out.

edit3:

```
CACHES              {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
SESSION_ENGINE      'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

Comment: i guess this issue comes when you don't have persistent session storage. and by default django does have it.

Comment: im working with a team, version controll via git - 2 of us 4 are affected by this. one of us since the beginning (but it seems not to bother him) and i am affected by this since a few weeks ago. 
as you can see in my post on the top, `expire_at_browser_close` is false which should be (according to the django api) enough for persistent sessions.

Further settings:
```SESSION_ENGINE    'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'```

Comment: Please show us your `SESSION_ENGINE` and `CACHES` settings.

Comment: `SESSION_ENGINE` as stated above is `'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'`
and `CACHES` is `{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}`
but i already tried others, it does not change anything

Answer (score 1):

Django has a [SESSION_ENGINE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#session-engine)  setting that controls how the session information is stored on the server. One of the options is `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache`, which stores session information only in cache memory.

Now, there's a certain cache backend - `django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache` -, which stores information in the local python memory (for more info see [CACHES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#caches)). This cache backend is a typical choice for development, and of course resets each time the server is reloaded.

Using these two settings together would perfectly explain the situation you describe. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I tested some settings but it does not change anything for the situation. First my caches variable was set to LocMemCache and i tried a few different, but i get logged out everytime i change a python file :/ which makes no sense at all even with different cache settings. the session key persists in the database and in my browser. they should recognize each other.

(session engine is set to my database)